# Sort fields inline

Tags: text-processing, awk, sort

I'm trying to sort within a line of input over an unknown number of fields:

Input:

```
ab bc
bc ab
cd ef bc 
bc cd ef
cd bc ab
ef ab bc cd gh
```

Output:

```
ab bc
ab bc
bc cd ef
bc cd ef
ab cb cd
ab bc cd ef gh
```

I've been using something like `awk '{if($2 < $1) print $2,$1;else print}'` but seems like it would get messy over more than two fields. Any help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way using `perl`:

```
perl -lane 'printf qq[%s\n], join q[ ], sort @F' infile
```

Output:

```
ab bc
ab bc
bc cd ef
bc cd ef
ab bc cd
ab bc cd ef gh
```

Comment: since you're using `-l`, you don't need to print a newline. `print join " ", sort @F` will suffice.

Answer (score 6):

One way using GNU awk:

```
awk '{ 
    split($0, arr); 
    asort(arr); 
    for (i=1; i<=length(arr); i++) { 
        printf "%s ", arr[i] }; 
        printf RS 
    }
' infile
```

Output:

```
ab bc 
ab bc 
bc cd ef 
bc cd ef 
ab bc cd 
ab bc cd ef gh
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another `perl` solution, similar to @Birei's answer but more concise:

```
$ perl -anle 'print "@{[sort @F]}"' file
ab bc
ab bc
bc cd ef
bc cd ef
ab bc cd
ab bc cd ef gh
```

Answer (score 1):

In shell script :

```
while read n    
do
   echo $(echo $n | tr " " "\n" | sort )
done < infile
```

(That forks too much, prefere the perl or gnu awk solution)