# Rearranging the column data based on alphabetical order

Tags: linux, awk

I want to change the order of column data based on alphabetical order

Input

```
c,a,b
e,k,d
```

Output

```
a,b,c
d,e,k
```

currently, I am using the below code

```
awk -F"," -v OFS="," '{ 
if($1<=$2 && $2<=$3) 
{print $1,$2,$3} 
else if($1<=$2 && $3<=$2) 
{print $1,$3,$2} 
else if($2<=$1 && $1<=$3) 
{print $2,$1,$3} 
else if($2<=$1 && $3<=$1) 
{print $2,$3,$1} 
else if($3<=$2 && $2<=$1) 
{print $3,$2,$1} 
else 
{print $3,$1,$2}}' test.txt
```

Could you please help me with a simpler solution to handle files having 4 or more columns

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/140388/116858

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU awk for sorted_in:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=","
}
{
    sub(/\r$/,"")
    print sort($0)
}

function sort(inStr,    arr,idx,sep,outStr) {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_str_asc"
    split(inStr,arr)
    for (idx in arr) {
        outStr = outStr sep arr[idx]
        sep = OFS
    }
    return outStr
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
a,b,c
d,e,k
```

or with any awk but will execute much slower since it's spawning a shell to call UNIX `sort` for each line of input:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=","
}
{
    sub(/\r$/,"")
    print sort($0)
}

function sort(inStr,    cmd,line,sep,outStr) {
    gsub(/,/,"\n",inStr)
    cmd = "printf \047%s\n\047 \047" inStr "\047 | sort"
    while ( (cmd | getline line) > 0 ) {
        outStr = outStr sep line
        sep = OFS
    }
    close(cmd)
    return outStr
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
a,b,c
d,e,k
```

The `sub(/\r$/,"")` is because you have DOS line endings in your posted sample input but not in your posted expected output.

Answer (score 3):

If you are okay with `perl`:

```
$ perl -F, -lane 'print join ",", sort @F' ip.txt
a,b,c
d,e,k
```

`-F,` specifies input line to be split with `,` as delimiter and result is available via `@F` array

`sort @F` will sort alphabetically and resulting array will be combined by `join` using `,` as separator

With `GNU awk`

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_str_asc"}
       {s = ""; c=0; split($0,a,",");
        for(k in a) s = c++ ? s "," a[k] : a[k];
        print s}' ip.txt
a,b,c
d,e,k
```

See [gawk manual: Using Predefined Array Scanning Orders](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html#Controlling-Scanning) for details about array ordering used above

Comment: For pre-4.0 gawks (which don't have the `PROCINFO` setting for array traversal) you could use `asort` ex. `nf=asort(a); for(k=1;k<=nf;k++) s = s ? s "," a[k] : a[k];`

Comment: Thanks both of you for your suggestions. I tried PROCINFO option and it is not sorting the data and for asort I am getting the error "function asort never defined"  Could you please provide me any other solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -nlE 'say join ",", sort split ","'   file.txt
```

Explanation:

```
            for each line like "r,d,a":
 "r,d,a"
    ↓          split ","  it
("r","d","a")
    ↓          sort       it
("a","d","r")
    ↓          join ","   it
 "a,d,r"
               say it
```